# Do you italicize the contraction attached to a foreign word?

Tags: word-usage, loanwords, italics

I know you italicize words in other languages when writing. But what if you add a contraction? Is it *abuela's* or *abuela*'s?

Comment: http://www.abuelos.com/locations/chandler-az-2/

Answer (score 2):

It's really a matter of style. Most style guides don't want you to use contractions (e.g. *'s* for *is*), so you'd resolve this by not using a contraction. If it's not actually a contraction but a possessive then the style guides I've seen suggest not italicizing the *apostrophe + s*. For example:

> Possessives [of foreign words] are often formed in the English manner, too:
>
> > The *chador*'s folds concealed her form.
>
> The *Chicago Manual of Style* practice—making the apostrophe and *s* roman—seems more acceptable here [than when forming a plural, as mentioned in a previous paragraph]; because of the separation provided by the apostrophe, the distinction is more apparent in printed type and less awkward-looking in typewriter underlining. But the same objections can be made by purists—a foreign word has been given an English inflection.
>
> I advise avoiding use of English plural and possessive inflections for italicized foreign words, but allowing an occasional exception to avoid awkward rephrasing. The lapse is a minor one.
> <sub>[The Handbook of Good English](https://books.google.com/books?id=n0IJ8GcdJ6IC&pg=PA259)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

This is purely stylistic as far as I know, but I would use "*abuela*'s".

Comment: If she is my grandmother then I would write Abuela's house/car/cat/etc and use Roman font.